# Another crockpot error

Tags: temperature, crockpot

I accidentally set my crockpot, with raw chicken and broth, on warm for a little less than one hour. I read answers to a similar question, but since this is chicken and only for 1 hour, I thought I'd ask if it's likely okay or not.

Answer (score 1):

If we go with the 2 hour rule, then you have about an hour to get it back up to a safe temperature.

So either turn the crockpot on high 'til you get it back over 140°F, or remove some of the broth and use another method to heat it and then re-combine the two.

Comment: Personally, I like going with a method mentioned on Good Eats -- get your liquid boiling, then add the chicken (so we kill off stuff that's on the outside, then reduce the heat so you maintain the desired finished temperature.  This allows you to come back in 2 to 6 hours, and the chicken's at the desired doneness.